# Stupid orange barrels left my car scuffed to hell

Tags: paint

I hit one of those stupid orange barrels on the interstate and it left possibly deep black scuffs on the side of my car...what are some good methods or something I can buy that doesn’t cost an arm and a leg to get rid of them

Comment: Images of the damage - is it surface or has it penetrated?

Comment: Why is the barrel stupid?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what type of paint finish you have but as a general rule cutting paste or rubbing compound will, used sparingly, remove any damage from the top of the paint.  It's worth pointing out though that this will be ineffective for damage which penetrates the paintwork through to base coat / primer or even metal below.  If that's the case, your only really effective option is to repaint the panel.

Answer (score 1):

I used to autocross and we removed cone-marks from paint with regular old paste wax. I would try that before progressing to the more aggressive cutting or rubbing compound, if necessary. As mentioned above the degree to which the paint finish was damaged will guide your actions.